# When would lambda functions be useful for classes in C++?

Tags: c++, lambda

So, I see the usefulness of lambda functions when they are used to replace functors, but when would you want to use them in an object oriented programming (with classes) setting in general and why?

Comment: @Sneftel: ah, thanks. I guess I was thinking there was more to it that just replacing functors.

Comment: Functors have types. Lambdas only have signatures.

Comment: I guess you're getting downvoted (partly) because we don't see why the words "object oriented programming" and "lambdas" are appearing in the same question. To me at least, there is no question here.

Comment: @user3528438 lambdas have types

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a little more (and less) helpful response than my comment.

Closures (that is, functions declared inside other functions, which capture the outer function's variables) are an interesting back-channel way to implement classes. Watch:

```
auto MakeCounter(int initialCount)
{
    int currentCount = initialCount;
    struct {
        std::function<void()> increment = [&]() { currentCount++; };
        std::function<int()> getCount = [&]() { return currentCount; };
    } theCounter;

    return theCounter;
}
```

Now `theCounter` is a structure with two members, one which increments the count and the other which retrieves the current count. Notice that the struct doesn't itself need to store the current count; that is instead implicitly held by the two lambdas, which share `currentCount` between them.

There's a few problems with this.

1. It doesn't compile. Not even mostly. There are a ton of things wrong with that code snippet. Actually, *it crashes GCC 4.9*. Whee!
2. Even if it did compile, it wouldn't work properly, because C++ closures aren't very powerful -- they can't keep captured variables alive after the end of their scopes. Only a language with actual GC could do this.
3. C++ already has classes, so why bother?

Nevertheless, you see this sort of pattern in other languages which either support (proper) closures and GC but don't have native facilities for classes (e.g. some variants of LISP), or do support classes but so crappily that it's arguably better to do things this way (e.g. Matlab).

So in C++ they're just for replacing functor boilerplate. They don't offer any additional power. In some other languages, they're rather more versatile, and more widely important.